# Getting ssl handshake error: "java.io.IOException: could not parse subject name" in j2me devices

Tags: ssl, java-me, bouncycastle, ioexception

i have created a j2me app and trying to access a server using https url. then i am getting following exception "java.io.IOException: could not parse subject name". i guess the protocol which is using to ssl handshake is SSLv3 from device. And as per secirity team i get to know that the server won't support SSLv3 because of some POODLE issue. We are able to hit this server uisng smart phone (Android, IOS, Windows) but not able to hit using j2me phones. is there any solution for this using any third party libraies like bouncy castle ?

Please advise.